# How to solve zend session variable inconsistentcy?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-variables

I am using the following ZEND session variable to store data

`$SSINamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('SSINamespace');
 $SSINamespace->my_id = 10;`

and access it according to my need in the next pages.

The problem that I am facing is that the value of this variable `$SSINamespace->my_id` is changing to 0 sometimes and its not retaining its original value. This error is not consistent but this happens once in 10 times.

I am not able to figure out the root cause of this intermittent issue.

Please suggest any possibilities. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link:- http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/zend-server.htm#session_clustering.htm.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Well, I am using the web app on a single server and the session lifetime is set to 30 mins already, Still I am getting this issue... Any other suggestions ??

Comment: MAY BE THE PROBLEM OCCUR because session timeout after 3 minute automatically. Mean to say in 10 time this happen once because the user is logged-in more that 30 minute or try to re-loggin or try to do anything after 3 min. please create session for longer time period and check

Comment: Ok try it and if  problem is solved. Please let me know.